# модуль распознавания речи python

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Вы не знаете модуль распознавания речи в python? Спасибо!

Comment: читаем https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/

Comment: О, я как-то интересовался этим, примеры: [консольный](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e175d546a8a50170ccdaaa5494648411397039b8/speech_recognition/microphone__google.py) и [оконное через pyqt5](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e175d546a8a50170ccdaaa5494648411397039b8/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/speech_recognition__microphone__google/main.py#L32)

Comment: @gil9red а у меня выводит ```Ошибка: No Default Input Device Available```

Comment: @Антон, микрофон должен быть определен

Comment: @gil9red спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модуль speech_recognition,

код для приема внешнего звука:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print ("Говорите!")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print ("Сервисы гугл анализируют вопрос!")
    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
    print(text)
```